# GA4 Why numbers of event count and conversions of the same conversion-marked event are different?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I had created the 'submission_complete' event on GTM and push it to GA4 report, then marked the event as conversion by toggle the switch on the GA4 event configure page.

I thought that after the event is marked as conversion, and the report is unsampled
, the number of event count and conversion of that event should be the same but apparently not.

Can anybody explain why this difference?
How the conversion event is counted differently from the event count?

I've tried to look for GA4 documentation about this but couldn't find, or understand, them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There seems to currently be an issue with GA4 marking events as conversions from web streams, which is a massive issue on my end. This seems to have started on the 23rd of August.

Comment: I am seeing this as well but my issue is for data on Aug 24.

Comment: Indeed. The issue has started on Aug 23 for my account. Hope Google fix this asap. I'll use 'event count' metric instead then. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes its same for one of my client's GA4, event is appearing but there is no conversion appear though it was marked as conversion, yes this issue arises in lat 3 days.